# Can't install cocos2d extensions

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-extensions-ios

I have cocos2d installed and working, but can't install cocos2d extensions.

I saw a a lot of tutorials from google and videos from youtube without success, I always get missing files error. I follow the tutorials step by step. First I delete the cocos2d empty folder from cocos2d extensions, then I create a new folder named cocos2d sources and add cocos2d folder from downloaded cocos2d source folder.

On right click on cocos2d sources folder, there is no "get into" option as tutorials show, since this option is missing in Xcode 4.5.2. So I checked cocos libraries and allTests when I add cocos2d folder, after building I get kazmath/kazmath.h missing files after adding kazmath folder, I had to change all input directories to point to kazmath files only not kazmat/kazmath.h for ej. and after that I got Mach O Linker error. Any help? Here are my screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/cocos1.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/cocos2.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/51/cocos3.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/cocos4.png/